# How to instantiate Main Window Form Correctly?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make instance of the Main Form1 but I don't know clearly where/how to do it.

in Main Program entry point there is  `Application.Run(new ProgramTalking());` do I replace it with 
`Form1 MyMainForm = new Form1();
MyMainForm.Show();` ?

I'm kinda lost in how to correctly instantiate and where to do it. For example I can instantiate my second Form2 and store it in memory but first Form1 just runs and I cant have any access to it from Form2 despite setting fields and properties to public. However I can effortlessly access Form2 from my From1. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the entry point of you program will be `Form1` instead of `ProgramTalking`, just replace

```
Application.Run(new ProgramTalking());
```

with

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

if you want `ProgramTalking` to open `Form1`, let's say on loading then you register to the right event (in this case form_load)

```
     this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

and do:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      new Form1().Show();// or .ShowDialog()
  }
```

Comment: this is all valid but how do I access my Form1 even if I will go with `Application.Run(new Form1());` there is still no way for me to access any fields and properties of this Form1 from my Form2 -  I need instance of Form1 to use/access it's fields and properties in Form2.

Comment: I have figured it out based on what you have provided. Thanks!